# How do I configure my DNS / DHCP / gateway server with 2 NICs to use its own DNS?

Tags: dns, bind, resolv.conf, isc-dhcpd, resolvconf

My SOHO lan is served by my main machine which operates as a router, firewall, gateway, DNS, DHCP server and backup server.

I've set up bind9 and isc-dhcp-server to do DDNS for the lan clients, while pppoe sets up the gateway to the net.

The backup server needs to recognise lan clients by hostname so I need it to look up their current IPs on the local DNS.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4

I got quite far (see [Dynamic DNS only serving DHCP clients, but new names not resolving on DNS server itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425001/dynamic-dns-only-serving-dhcp-clients-but-new-names-not-resolving-on-dns-server) for the `bind9 - dhcpd - ddns` setup I did) but I still haven't managed to configure local DNS look-ups on the server.

The server's `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
adam@gondor:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 81.139.56.100
nameserver 81.139.57.100
domain localdomain
search localdomain
```

This is I assume being written at boot by `pppoe` which configures the gateway. There's a `/etc/ppp/resolv.conf` that is the same, but I'm not sure  what role it plays.

My question is how I should configure linux so that `backuppc` will do DNS on the localhost for domain names on the lan, and yet browsing the net in firefox on the same machine will also work.

A colleague advised me to put `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` but that doesn't seem to be a good idea:

```
adam@gondor:~$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

I'm also *not* using `network-manager` to control `pppoe` which seems to be a popular choice.

**[UPDATE After 1st comment]** I looked more into the `resolvconf` package and discovered that it was out-of-date. I've updated it but I'm now pretty sure that the warning in `head` above is warning me not to edit `resolv.conf` manually, rather than `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

It also didn't help that http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/resolvconf.8.html talks about files that `resolvconf` isn't giving me, like `resolvconf.conf`.

I have also decided that `pppd` can't be using `resolvconf`, so I have disabled it from updating `/etc/resolv.conf` by commenting out the `updatedns` option in `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider`. I don't want the British Telecom DNS servers anyway, I'm going to configure `resolvconf` to use `127.0.0.1`, and I'll tell `bind9` to forward to the OpenDNS servers instead.

Comment: To my knowledge, for DNS queries to your server, the interface name server should be 127.0.0.1.  So, I would use that inside `/etc/resolv.conf` as nameserver instead of the two you listed.  If your server needs to resolve names itself, it uses the forwarders set up in `/etc/named.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

`pppd` was controlling `/etc/resolv.conf` so the first thing I had to do was take out the ppp option which told it to pass through the British Telecom DNS servers. That was in `usepeerdns` in `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider`.

Then I purged and re-installed the `resolvconf` package out of frustration, and re-installing it actually set it up as it is documented (almost) at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/resolvconf.8.html

I put `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` so now it appears in the `/etc/resolv.conf` or better said in the `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` file linked to.

I tweaked my `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
acl goodclients {
    localhost;
    localnets;
};

options {
        listen-on {
                192.168.0.3;
                127.0.0.1;
        };
        listen-on-v6 {
                fe80::2a37:37ff:fe03:4225/64;
                ::1;
                #any;                                                                                                                                                    
        };
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
                208.67.220.220;
                208.67.222.222;
        };
        allow-query { goodclients; };
        allow-recursion { goodclients; };
        allow-transfer { goodclients; };
        dnssec-enable no;
        #dnssec-validation auto;                                                                                                                                         
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035                                                                                                                        
};
```

One article I was following told me to put `192.168.0.0/24` in my `acl goodclients` block, and also to use `dnssec-validation auto;` but they caused a whole raft of errors to be logged in `syslog` so I took them out again.

It would also work without the `forwarders` block where I put the OpenDNS DNS servers, but without them, lots of IPv6 network unreachable errors.